# edit homepage text in source file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fix some text on the homepage prototype created by a company for my dad. I viewed their prototype homepage in a browser, right-clicked, viewed and downloaded the page source, and created my own copy of it. Now, I intended to manually edit the text fields in the source files so that, in the end, we just have to send them copies of the edited source files with the fixed text fields.

If I move the to parts in the source that has the text I want to change, and I change this text, then, upon saving and opening the file in a browser, the changes are sometimes visible but other times not.
EG. here, if I change the specified text, the changes are not visible upon reopening.

```
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-3efde4d elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="3efde4d" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                        <p>TEXT I WANT TO CHANGE</p>                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-509c8d79 elementor-align-left elementor-widget elementor-widget-button" data-id="509c8d79" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="button.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
```

Now, while I do program in C++ and Python, I have no clue at all of HTML and web development. Let me know whether my approach is not going to work... There are certain links in the source as well, leading to the servers of the company. Looks like some text fields are somehow protected by these links?

Comment: You really gave too little information. How do you open the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing the string `elementor` in the page source your browser gets from the server should tip you off *strongly* that the [Elementor](https://elementor.com/) WYSIWYG tool is in use here, which would also necessitate a [WordPress](https://wordpress.org)-based backend.

As such, it's a very safe assumption that the HTML you're seeing here is generated by a *highly* complex web of back-end technology which you wouldn't be privy to simply by visiting the publicly-facing part of this site.

To answer your questions directly:

> Let me know whether my approach is not going to work

It's unlikely, as there are intricate interdependencies at play here that would probably break or cease to function as intended when manually updated outside the WYSIWYG editor that seems to be in place here.

> There are certain links in the source as well, leading to the servers of the company. Looks like some text fields are somehow protected by these links?

"*Protected*" might be a bit of a misnomer, but it appears that the company that generated the initial website has dependencies on their own servers for resources in use on the site in question.

> homepage prototype created by a company

This generally also indicates that you likely have some sort of contract or other agreement with this company to perform these changes, which you should work through them to have completed. Manually updating raw HTML source you've retrieved from your browser will not provide much value (if any at all) if this back-end complexity is indeed in place here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I began to think that it was not going to work that easily. I thought editing the source code myself was easier than taking screenshots of the dozen parts that I want them to change...